# Need explanation about this PS code computing elements < 100 in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: powershell

I understand what this code does but not how it does.

```
$($c=$p=1; while ($c -lt 100) {$c; $c,$p=($c+$p),$c})
```

This part `{$c; $c,$p=($c+$p),$c}` is processed at every loop. I get it but I don’t understand the `$c,$p=($c+$p),$c` part. Is it an array, here ? Can someone explain what really happens at every loop ?

Here is what I think what happens.

- `$c;` allows to display the current value to output.
- `$c,$p=($c+$p),$c` computes the next value in Fibonacci sequence and update `$c` and `$p` that are equal. But why this array-like syntax ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
$c= $p = 1 # $c = 1, $p = 1

while ($c -lt 100) # while $c is lower than 100
{
    $c # $c to Standard Output

    $c, $p = ($c+$p), $c
    # ($c + $p) is processed first, on first iteration 1+1
    # 2, $c this generates an array @(2, 1) on first iteration
    # $c, $p = This assigns the position 0 of the array to $c
    # and position 1 to $p
}
```

If you really want to break down the code this would be more or less (I'm sorry if this is not 100% accurate) what is happening:

```sh
$c = $p = 1

while ($c -lt 100)
{
    $c
    
    $temp1 = $c + $p
    $temp2 = $c

    $c = $temp1
    $p = $temp2
}
```

From MS Docs [about Assignment Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.1#assigning-multiple-variables)

> In PowerShell, you can assign values to multiple variables by using a single command. The first element of the assignment value is assigned to the first variable, the second element is assigned to the second variable, the third element to the third variable, and so on. This is known as **multiple assignment**.

#### Example

```
PS /> $one,$two = 'one','two'
PS /> $one
one

PS /> $two
two

PS /> $one,$two = @(
'one'
'two'
)

PS /> $one
one

PS /> $two
two
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. I had forgotten the multiple assignments feature in PS or my brain couldn’t infer it in this inline form for some reasons.

Comment: I added a break down of what is "happening" even tho it's not 100% accurate :)

Comment: @FredEric I think Python has a multiple variable assignment too, I might be wrong tho